# Simplification problem

Tags: calculus, vectors

OK I'm really ashamed I can't figure this out 
[image]

Now they have simplified this to give the following

[image]

My questions is why is it c'(t) and not c'(ti)

Comment: It is one way to define integrals [Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Connection_with_integration). See how in the formula in the link the expression on the right has the sequence $x_i$, while the one on the left, doesn't. The one on the left is just notation. But it doesn't have any reference to the sequence $x_i$ to indicate that it doesn't depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first, the $(t_i)$ are a sequence of sample ordinates in the interval $[a,b]$.  In the second, $t$ ranges through every value in $[a,b]$.  That is, the former is a discrete approximation to the latter.  In the latter, the variable $t$ varies continuously from $a$ to $b$, not in jumps between samples.

Compare with what happens in the (limit of a) [Riemann sum definition of the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Connection_with_integration).